# set multiple values to combobox

Tags: c#, combobox, ext.net

i have a combobox with the multiselect option , i want to set a multiple value from
codebehind , here is my store :

```
<ext:Store ID="StoreT"    runat="server" PageSize="10">
        <Model>
            <ext:Model ID="Model3" runat="server">
                <Fields>
                    <ext:ModelField Name="name" />
                    <ext:ModelField Name="code" />
                </Fields>
            </ext:Model>
        </Model>
</ext:Store>

<ext:ComboBox ID="ComboBoxT"  MultiSelect="true" StoreID="StoreT" DisplayField="name" ValueField="code">
</ext:ComboBox>
```

i want to pass to setValues multiple codes as selected at the same time .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use a ComboBox's SelectedItems.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>

<script runat="server">
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!X.IsAjaxRequest)
        {
            Store store = this.ComboBox1.GetStore();
            store.DataSource = new object[] 
            { 
                new object[] { "1", "Item 1" },
                new object[] { "2", "Item 2" },
                new object[] { "3", "Item 3" },
                new object[] { "4", "Item 4" }
            };
        }
    }

    protected void SetValues(object sender, DirectEventArgs e)
    {
        this.ComboBox1.SelectedItems.Clear();
        this.ComboBox1.SelectedItems.Add(new Ext.Net.ListItem { Value = "2" });
        this.ComboBox1.SelectedItems.Add(new Ext.Net.ListItem { Value = "4" });
        this.ComboBox1.UpdateSelectedItems();
    }
</script>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head runat="server">
    <title>Ext.NET v2 Example</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form runat="server">
        <ext:ResourceManager runat="server" />

        <ext:Button runat="server" Text="Set 2 and 4" OnDirectClick="SetValues" />

        <ext:ComboBox 
            ID="ComboBox1" 
            runat="server" 
            DisplayField="text" 
            ValueField="value"
            MultiSelect="true">
            <Store>
                <ext:Store runat="server">
                    <Model>
                        <ext:Model runat="server">
                            <Fields>
                                <ext:ModelField Name="value" />
                                <ext:ModelField Name="text" />
                            </Fields>
                        </ext:Model>
                    </Model>
                    <Reader>
                        <ext:ArrayReader />
                    </Reader>
                </ext:Store>
            </Store>
            <SelectedItems>
                <ext:ListItem Value="1" />
                <ext:ListItem Value="3" />
            </SelectedItems>
        </ext:ComboBox>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```